# encodeURIComponent and urldecode removes slashes, why?

Tags: php, json, encodeuricomponent

Hello
I am using JSON.stringify for an array of arrays, and it returns this:

```
'[
  ["<span pt=\"7.5\" idfont=\"Humnst777 Cn BT-Bold\">Javelin</span>","0","0"],
  ["<span idfont=\"Humnst777 Cn BT-Bold\">Javelin&co</span>","0","0"]
 ]';
```

It is correct but i have to use encodeURIComponent (& present) to post this value with js.
The problem is that when I get this data in POST from php with $boxes=json_decode($_POST['data']) it seems to remove slashes eg. pt=\"7.5\" -> pt="7.5" destroying the json object giving this result:

```
'[
["<span pt="7.5" idfont="Humnst777 Cn BT-Bold" >Javelin</span>","0","0"]
["<span pt="7.5" idfont="Humnst777 Cn BT-Bold" >Javelin&</span>","0","0"]

 ]';
```

Does any one how to avoid this problem?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have magic_quotes activated ?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Answer (score 0):

Try rawurlencode and rawurldecode instead. Ref [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) for more details